# SharedPreferences not saving after .commit() or .apply() in Fragment

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Framgent Class

```
public class FragmentSignUp1 extends Fragment {

    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextUsername;

    UserSignUpPreferences userSignUpPreferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup1, container, false);
        userSignUpPreferences = new UserSignUpPreferences(this.getActivity());

        //  Creating references to Views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);

        // Setting custom font on elements
        return view;
    }

//  Restore data if activity has been destroyed
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        } else {
            editTextEmail.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("email"));
            editTextUsername.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("username"));
        }
    }

//  Save data if activity is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("email", editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("username", editTextUsername.getText().toString());
    }

//  Save data if activity get paused
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("fragment_signup1", editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        userSignUpPreferences.editor.putString(editTextEmail.getText().toString(), userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL)
        .putString(editTextUsername.getText().toString(), userSignUpPreferences.USER_USERNAME)
        .apply();
        Log.d("fragment_signup1", userSignUpPreferences.preferences.getString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL, "null"));
    }

//  Retrieve data when activity is resumed
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("fragment_signup1", userSignUpPreferences.preferences.getString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL, "null"));
        editTextEmail.setText(userSignUpPreferences.preferences.getString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL, "2"));
        editTextUsername.setText(userSignUpPreferences.preferences.getString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_USERNAME, ""));
    }
}
```

UserPreferences Class

```
public class UserPreferences {

    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public SharedPreferences preferences;

    public UserPreferences(Context context, String prefFileName) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(prefFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }
}
```

UserSignUpPreferences Class

```
public class UserSignUpPreferences extends  UserPreferences{

    private final static String USER_SEARCH_SETTINGS = "UserSearchSettingsPrefFile";
    public final String USER_EMAIL = "email";
    public final String USER_USERNAME = "username";

    public UserSignUpPreferences(Context context) {
        super(context, USER_SEARCH_SETTINGS);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that... it doesn't save the current values..why?

Comment: @MikeM.
in fragment onPause() method there is .apply()

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameters reversed when applying the values.
The first parameter of [putString()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is the key that you use for lookup, and the second parameter is the value associated with the key.

Reverse them here and it should work:

```
//  Save data if activity get paused
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("fragment_signup1", editTextEmail.getText().toString());
    userSignUpPreferences.editor.putString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL, editTextEmail.getText().toString())
    .putString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_USERNAME, editTextUsername.getText().toString())
    .apply();
    Log.d("fragment_signup1", userSignUpPreferences.preferences.getString(userSignUpPreferences.USER_EMAIL, "null"));
}
```